# Update un-null columns from 2 source tables into null columns of target table

Tags: sql

I have TABLE A

```
ID|POS|Location|ITEM    |COLOR
------------------------------
1 | 1 |ABC     |A       | RED
1 | 2 |ABC     |B       | BLUE
1 | 3 |ABC     |NULL    | YELLOW
1 | 4 |ABC     |D       | NULL
2 | 1 |ABC     |A       | BLACK
2 | 2 |ABC     |B       | BLUE
2 | 3 |ABC     |C       | RED
3 | 1 |ABC     |NULL    | BROWN
4 | 1 |ABC     |A       | WHITE
4 | 2 |ABC     |B       | RED  
4 | 3 |ABC     |NULL    | BLUE 
4 | 4 |ABC     |NULL    | YELLOW
5 | 1 |ABC     |A       | NULL
5 | 2 |ABC     |C       | NULL
5 | 3 |ABC     |D       | BLUE
6 | 1 |ABC     |A       | RED
6 | 2 |ABC     |B       | BROWN
6 | 3 |ABC     |C       | WHITE
7 | 1 |ABC     |NULL    | RED 
7 | 2 |ABC     |B       | NULL
7 | 3 |ABC     |C       | YELLOW
8 | 1 |ABC     |A       | NULL
8 | 2 |ABC     |B       | BLACK
8 | 3 |ABC     |C       | BLUE
8 | 4 |ABC     |D       | RED
8 | 5 |ABC     |E       | BROWN
9 | 1 |ABC     |NULL    | WHITE
9 | 2 |ABC     |C       | BLUE
9 | 3 |ABC     |D       | YELLOW
9 | 4 |ABC     |E       | NULL
10 | 1 |ABC     |A       | NULL
10 | 2 |ABC     |B       | WHITE
10 | 3 |ABC     |C       | BLACK
11 | 1 |ABC     |A       | BLUE
11 | 2 |ABC     |B       | NULL
```

TABLE B

```
ID|POS|Location|ITEM    
1 | 1 |ABC     |A       
1 | 2 |ABC     |B       
1 | 3 |ABC     |B       
1 | 4 |ABC     |D       
2 | 1 |ABC     |A       
2 | 2 |ABC     |B       
2 | 3 |ABC     |C       
3 | 1 |ABC     |E       
4 | 1 |ABC     |A       
4 | 2 |ABC     |B       
4 | 3 |ABC     |F       
4 | 4 |ABC     |NULL    
5 | 1 |ABC     |A       
5 | 2 |ABC     |C       
5 | 3 |ABC     |NULL      
6 | 1 |ABC     |A       
6 | 2 |ABC     |B
```

and TABLE C

```
ID|POS|Location   |COLOR
--------------------------
1 | 1 |ABC        | RED
1 | 2 |ABC        | BLUE
1 | 3 |ABC        | YELLOW
1 | 4 |ABC        | RED
2 | 1 |ABC        | BLACK
2 | 2 |ABC        | BLUE
2 | 3 |ABC        | VIOLET
3 | 1 |ABC        | BROWN
4 | 1 |ABC        | WHITE
4 | 2 |ABC        | RED
4 | 3 |ABC        | BLUE 
4 | 4 |ABC        | YELLOW
5 | 1 |ABC        | WHITE 
5 | 2 |ABC        | BLACK
5 | 3 |ABC        | BLUE 
6 | 1 |ABC        | RED  
6 | 2 |ABC        | BROWN
6 | 3 |ABC        | WHITE
7 | 1 |ABC        | RED  
7 | 2 |ABC        | BLUE 
7 | 3 |ABC        | YELLOW
8 | 1 |ABC        | PURPLE 
8 | 2 |ABC        | BLACK
8 | 3 |ABC        | PINK 
8 | 4 |ABC        | RED  
8 | 5 |ABC        | BROWN
9 | 1 |ABC        | WHITE
9 | 2 |ABC        | BLUE 
9 | 3 |ABC        | YELLOW
9 | 4 |ABC        | NULL 
10 | 1 |ABC        | CYAN
10 | 2 |ABC        | WHITE
10 | 3 |ABC        | BLACK
11 | 1 |ABC        | INDIGO
11 | 2 |ABC        | NULL
```

I want to copy the Items column from Table B (not null items) and Colors column from Table C (not null colors) to update them into Table A only if the Item column is null or color item in Table A is null.

Thanks,

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your keys are ID and POS? If you are using sql server then you can do this with a case statement

```
UPDATE a
set 
   item = CASE WHEN b.item is not null then b.item else a.item END,
   color = CASE WHEN c.color is not null then c.color else a.color END
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
on a.ID = b.ID and a.POS = b.POS
INNER JOIN TableC c
on a.ID = c.ID and a.POS = c.POS
```

Comment: Key is ID but not POS.

Comment: @Jay2012 so then are you trying to update all records with ID = 1 to the same thing? Seems to me that you want to also join on POS so you can get the unique record to update

Comment: First, I will have to copy any mismatched values from Table B into null value table A. 
If there is not a null value in table A for that ID. I will have to insert it. Of course,
the color value is a null if I do insert record from Table B into table A. Value in ID 1 of
table B will not be copied since there is A, B and D value in ID1 of table A. Because, value E
in ID3 of table B is not in table A, and there is a null value in ID3 of table A. Update value
E into ID3 null value in table A.

Comment: Here is my query   
UPDATE   
    TableA   
SET   
    Item = CASE WHEN B.item is not null then B.item else A.item END,    
FROM   
    TableA AS A   
INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON A.ID = B.ID    
WHERE A.POS = A.POS   

So far, I only got all those copied if the position are matched. But if the position are not matched from these 2 tables, it is not working.

Comment: Right so lets look at an example (ID = 1). If you only have a key on ID that is shared between the two tables (table A and table B) then when you go to update ID =1, POS = 3 in table A because it is a null item. If you join on only ID then you will pull in all the records containing that ID ( 16 results ) thats why I thought POS was also part of the key.

Comment: Right, that is the problem, I am thinking using row_number() function. I want only copy 1 value from B into 1 null value of Color column on A instead of (16 results) with the same ID. Else, I will insert it to the next new position with same ID.

Comment: I would suggest using some row function as well